# Could not read JSON: Unrecognized character escape ' '

Tags: java, spring, http, jackson

JSON could not be mapped with `@RequestBody` Map reqParam in my spring controller. It's working in following JSON.

```
{strNote : "\\\\"},{strNote : "\"},{strNote : "/"},{strNote : "//"}
```

While it's not working for `{strNote : "a\\b"}`. As and when I try to send this JSON, it gives following exception.

> Exception : MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java -
>   readJavaType():181 - Could not read JSON: Unrecognized character
>   escape ' ' (code 32) at [Source:
>   (myProject.Auth.filter.ServletInputStreamWrapper); line: 1, column:
>   43]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character
>   escape ' ' (code 32)]

Comment: Please post the full document for which the parsing fails. Column 43, FWIW...

Answer (score 0):

You got an error, because you should terminate your `\b`. It recognizes like backspace or space, as you see.

See [here](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/backspace-ascii-code-8.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helps. What is best way to encode this ?

Comment: If you need your `{strNote : "a\b"}` you should make it like `{strNote : "a\\b"}`. Like **@Julian Reschke** ask in the first comment, show us your full document and we`ll try to help you